# unknown exception error when I run Notepad++ v6.8.2 when starting Regex Helper

Tags: notepad++, regex

I get an unknown exception error in Notepad++ v6.8.2 when starting Regex Helper?  Any suggestions?

OS: Win7 64-bit
Installed with installer package

Comment: Just to note the exception is there for very long time, perhaps since the N++ **6.0**.

Answer (score 1):

#### I get an unknown exception error in Notepad++ v6.8.2 when starting Regex Helper.

Downloading Regex Helper using the Plugin Manager installs version 0.2.2 (which is not the latest version and gives the "unknown exception" error).

There is a ticket for this:

> Please update plugin 2.3 in repo. Still installing 2.2 hence the old (and closed) issue repoped.
>   I downloaded 2.3 and placed it in plugin folder, now it works fine.

Source [#10 Plugin manager still downloads RegEx Helper 2.2 - crashing on Win10-64](http://sourceforge.net/p/nppregexhelper/bugs/10/)

**Workaround**:

1. Close notepad++.
2. Download the lastest version (0.2.3) directly using the download button on [RegEx Helper: a notepad++ plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppregexhelper/).
3. Copy `nppRegEx.dll` into `Notepad++\plugins`.
4. Start notepad++.

[image]